# Tailwind + Next 13 - Default background-color not present in .css when used in a component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm learning more about Tailwind & Next JS.

I am trying to create a local `Button` component that has `variant` and `size` based on props, which will resolve in Tailwind strings at the end, and those will be merged by `tailwind-merge` with `clsx`.

I noticed that the background color that is resolved (e.g. `bg-blue-500`) is not present in the CSS file, and it is not displayed.

However, when I used the color on `page.tsx`, the color is shown (and it is now shown in the button too).

The Tailwind configuration is the default, generated by `create-next-app --tailwind`.

**classnames.ts**

```
import { ClassValue, clsx } from 'clsx'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

export function classnames(...classes: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(classes))
}
```

**button.const.ts**

```
export const enum ButtonVariant {
  PRIMARY = 'primary',
  SECONDARY = 'secondary',
  DANGER = 'danger',
  SUCCESS = 'success',
  WARNING = 'warning',
}

export const enum ButtonSize {
  SMALL = 'small',
  MEDIUM = 'medium',
  LARGE = 'large',
}

export const BUTTON_TW_COLORS: Record<ButtonVariant, string> = {
  [ButtonVariant.PRIMARY]: 'bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700',
  [ButtonVariant.SECONDARY]: 'bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-700',
  [ButtonVariant.DANGER]: 'bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700',
  [ButtonVariant.SUCCESS]: 'bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700',
  [ButtonVariant.WARNING]: 'bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yellow-700',
}

export const BUTTON_TW_SIZES: Record<ButtonSize, string> = {
  [ButtonSize.SMALL]: 'px-3 py-2 text-sm',
  [ButtonSize.MEDIUM]: 'px-3.5 py-2.5 text-base',
  [ButtonSize.LARGE]: 'px-4 py-2 text-lg',
}
```

**button.tsx**

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react'

import { BUTTON_TW_COLORS, BUTTON_TW_SIZES, ButtonSize, ButtonVariant } from '@/constants/button.const'
import { classnames } from '@/libs/utils'

export interface ButtonPropos {
  children: ReactNode
  className?: string
  onClick?: () => void
  variant?: ButtonVariant
  size?: ButtonSize
}

export function Button({
  children,
  className,
  onClick,
  variant = ButtonVariant.PRIMARY,
  size = ButtonSize.MEDIUM,
}: ButtonPropos) {
  const classNames = classnames('font-bold rounded-md', BUTTON_TW_COLORS[variant], BUTTON_TW_SIZES[size], className)

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={classNames}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

**page.tsx**

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant={ButtonVariant.SECONDARY}>
        Book an Appointment
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Result:**
[image: No bg-color]